# How to merging DB between two servers?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here are my process for now:

1. Fixing bugs or install new plugins on locally (Using Git for source version control)
2. Deploy code to hosting via FTP or SFTP (No SSH)
3. Sync DB between locally and staging (or live site) with  https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db

The problem that I'm facing now is how to deal with new data was created from Live site. I want to merge these new records with staging DB or locally without losing my own data.

Please help me solve this issue. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: I remember a while ago someone released a plugin to solve this problem. It might be this one, but it does exist. https://deliciousbrains.com/database-merging-made-easy/

Comment: It's not release yet. Anw, thanks for your help.